Migration Xamarin.iOS to .net for iOS Problems, Ideas, Questions
I'm in the process of migrating a Xamarin.iOS project to .NET for iOS. I've conducted tests and found myself in a waiting game. Time is slowly passing, and questions are multiplying rather than disappearing. It's May 2024. We still don't know what the future holds for .NET for iOS and whether it makes sense as a native project. There's still no synchronization of Storyboard and xib files with the C# dev kit (especially with the withdrawal of support for VS for Mac), so for now, it's either waiting, switching to Rider, or manual tinkering. But there's no certainty whether Microsoft will abandon it if they themselves don't want to pursue it.
The second problem is the migration direction: is it better to go with pure .NET for iOS or try native embedding and hybrid development, which would eventually transition into a .NET Maui application? What do you think about this? Do you have any information, advice, or ideas?
Well, Rider works, but I somehow can't sleep peacefully knowing that Microsoft isn't doing anything to solve the problem.
Update:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/571?fbclid=IwZXh0bgNhZW0CMTAAAR1D6l-h1z6qTh7d-6xs-up-Q0SANBdNbGLKuLhe9ofvPF9SFyG8-CYwoH8_aem_AdLenTqdg8A1unpcKYcrrmMa7XRUBnqMkTOEojdhwiPfED9A6YGcJjgNAHr6Fcd1kPlCsIh0EiMSIwJBe53zwn8P#issuecomment-2113414637

Please read [ask] before posting.  This is off topic

Advice for all times - choose technologies that are used by big companies for their own, main projects.
Example - React Native is used by Facebook in Facebook app, Messenger, Instagram etc.
